# Not able to connect with SQL Server Express database instance on AWS thorugh Web Service

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sql-server-express

I have created a SQL Server Express database instance on AWS (Amazon Web Service). I'm able to connect to it from my local PC using a Windows application.

I have created an ASP.net test web application.

Structure:

Web Application ⇒ Web Service ⇒　Database Instance

I have hosted the web application on AWS (AWS Support Tool) by creating environment.

AWS Environment:

Way 1: Created environment (Windows Server 2012 R2 + IIS)

Not included Database in it. My database connection code is in Web Service part. which is also published on AWS. I am connecting to the Database instance which I have created previously. [Able to connect to it By SQL Management studio from my local PC].

But when I am trying to run deployed (AWS) application failed to connect it.
With above same setting when my [Web App + Web Service] is published on my local PC. DB is on AWS then its work fine.

I don't know what is the problem for database connection when everything is on AWS. Throwing Below Exception.

> Message: Server was unable to process request. ---> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) ---> The parameter is incorrect

Connection String:

```
Data Source=XXXXXX.YYYYYYYY.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=Test;Password=Test
```

Way 2: I have crated Created environment (Windows Server 2012 R2 + IIS + SQL Database) on AWS.

Still same error occurs.

I don't know which setting is going wrong.

i.e Deployment procedure or environment(Group Security setting) is wrong.

Any idea or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above issue was occurred because of not insufficeint Security Group setting...

I have added below inbound rule to Security group to allow access to SQL server on specified port number.

> Type(MS SQL) 
>   
> Protocol(TCP) 
>   
> Port Range(1433) 
>   
> Source(0.0.0.0/0)

With above setting successfully made the database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Q) Data Source=XXXXXX.YYYYYYYY.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:1433;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=Test;Password=Test

A) Data Source=XXXXXX.YYYYYYYY.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=Test;Password=Test

Note: Before port no. (i,e) 1433 instead of ':' we can put ','.